# Java/MySQL dao storing nulls values and nullpointerexceptions - keeping it simple

Tags: java, mysql, sql, dao

I am using a simple DAO for my app. It's MySQL 5.5 and the MySQL Connector for Java. I'm not using a framework in a hope to keep things simple. I'm just using EclipseLink JPA to create the model objects and then coding the daos by hand.

The DAO creates a user object which includes some optional fields to store IDs to other tables. I'm storing IDs as Long. When the object is created, the ID fields are null. This is okay with me because those other tables are optional for the user. So... in the database, the ID fields could be Long or nulls. MySQL is okay with this too.

But when I try to store the user object with my DAO, it barfs on the null value going into a Long. See code below.

I know I could test for nulls and set the IDs to zero instead. But that's no more correct than null. And that's extra work.

What's the most efficient way to deal with this situation? Default them to 0 when I create the first object? Seems like a fudge.

I'm also open to constructive criticism on the way I create the new record. I see having a separate addUser and updateUser as being more error prone due to duplication. This seemed more efficient. Comments?

Thanks

```
public User updateUser(User user) {
    Connection conn = DbUtil.getConnection();
    PreparedStatement ps;
    Statement st;
    ResultSet rs;

    try {

        if (user.getId()==null) {
            st = conn.createStatement();
            st.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO users (created, modified) VALUES(NOW(), NOW());");
            rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() AS id;");
            if (rs.next()) {
                Long id = rs.getLong("id");
                user.setId(id);
            }
        }

        String SQLupdate = "UPDATE users SET "
                + "travid      = ?, "
                + "busid       = ?, "
                + "email       = ?, "
                + "type        = ?, "
                + "name        = ?, "
                + "handle      = ?, "
                + "password    = ?, "
                + "passencr    = ?, "
                + "passhint    = ?, "
                + "question    = ?, "
                + "answer      = ?, "
                + "modified    = NOW(), "
                + "lastlogin   = ? "
                + "WHERE id    = ?";

        ps = conn.prepareStatement(SQLupdate);          
        ps.setLong(  1, user.getTravid());
        ps.setLong(  2, user.getBusid());
        ps.setString(3, user.getEmail());
        ps.setString(4, user.getType());
        ps.setString(5, user.getName());
        ps.setString(6, user.getHandle());
        ps.setString(7, user.getPassword());
        ps.setString(8, user.getPassencr());
        ps.setString(9, user.getPasshint());
        ps.setString(10, user.getQuestion());
        ps.setString(11, user.getAnswer());
        ps.setObject(12, user.getLastlogin());
        ps.setLong(13, user.getId());
        ps.executeUpdate();

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();

    } finally {
        DbUtil.close(conn);
    }

    return user;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please review the JDBC API. You don't write null values to the database by setting a null with `PreparedStatement.setXxxx(index,null)`.  Use the method `setNull(index,sqlType)` instead.

Comment: What I was actually hoping for was a way to set it in the database in a way that would tolerate a null as well as an Integer - and without having to code around the situation. For now, I initialize the IDs to zero to avoid the null. Then I check when I use them for >0 to see if it's a real value. Effectively replacing the null with a zero. Just wanted to know if there was a better way... Thanks

Comment: You could set a default value in the table definition and then not even set the value in the Java code.

Comment: Yeah. I suppose that would be the easiest... Thanks